# a short phrase for 'exert strength with the hand'

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for a way to translate the Portuguese phrase 'fazer força com a mão', which literaly translates as 'to exert strength with the hand'.

I've searched the Internet and I came across a lot of 'hand grip strength' but not a verb that could fit the bill. I've also toyed with phrases such as 'apply strength', but they just don't feel natural.

I'd like something that could fit sentences such as:
- She *exerted strength with her hand* and hurt herself.
- She had to *exert a lot of strength with her hand* before she could open the lid.
- She couldn't *exert strength with her hand* because of her hurt thumb.

edit:
The phrase should imply that there is a strong grip (which is mostly stationary) followed by exerting strength to produce a (twisting, horizontal, vertical, what you may) movement. In a sense, it's a "strong grip immediately followed by strong production of movement".

Comment: Does *grip* or *grip hard* fit the bill? It's difficult to tell from the examples exactly what is required.

Comment: Grip does not convey the sense of applying strength to cause movement (I believe). You can grip the lid as hard as you want, it will not open until you exert that strength into producing a twisting movement to remove the lid. So it's more than just grip, it's to grip and cause a movement, all requiring strength.

Comment: Aha. That's useful. Could you edit that clarification into the question?

Comment: Push, press, squeeze, pound.

Comment: Consider "act with a steady hand".

Comment: It it necessary to find one phrase or word to cover all three situations in your OP or may we consider an apt phrase or word for each of the three?

Comment: For (2) and maybe (3), how about *firm grasp* – *you need a firm grasp to open that lid.*

Comment: @PeterPoint: I'd rather one phrase for the three, but will accept more if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your direct translation could be improved. Although it is possible in English to "exert your strength" it is also possible to "exert a force". "Force" is a direct translation of "força" and is more appropriate in your examples.

In order to make your examples more natural in English, I've also reworded/added some extra words:

Instead of "She couldn't exert strength with her hand because of her hurt thumb" I would say:

> She couldn't exert **any** force with her hand because of her hurt thumb

Instead of "She had to exert a lot of strength with her hand before she could open the lid" I would say:

> She had to exert a lot of force with her hand **in order to** open the lid

Your first example, however, I am finding more problematic. Your example is "She exerted strength with her hand and hurt herself". As we don't really have a stock idiomatic phrase for "using the strength of your hand", this sentence feels to me like it's missing context, i.e. what she was trying to do with her hand. My best attempt would be to include the "lid opening" context:

> She tried opening the lid by hand, but hurt herself.

Answer (score 1):

## [yank](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/yank)

> to pull something forcefully with a quick movement:

- She hurt her hand when she **yanked** the jar lid **off**.
- She couldn't **yank** the lid **off** because her thumb hurt.
- She **yanked** hard **at** the rope but hurt her hand in the process.
- *‘In a couple of strides, Sonrisa made her way to the door, **yanking** it open **with force**.’*

and as a noun ...

- *‘Eventually with **a hefty yank** and a banshee-like howl, the damn thing came out.’*
  <sup>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/yank)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

1. She couldn't **summon up dexterity** because of her hurt thumb.

**Summon up:** To call upon for specified action. (M-W)

**Dexterity:** The ability to perform a difficult action quickly and skillfully with the hands...(Cambridge Dictionary)

2. She had to **manhandle** it before she could open the lid.

**Manhandle:** To handle roughly. (Free Dictionary)

3. By resorting to **fisticuffs** she hurt herself.

**Fisticuffs:** To fight with fists. (M-W)

Comment: @Sara Costa  Noted. I'll try to come up with one phrase for the three I've offered. Stay tuned.

Comment: Have you given up on finding one single phrase or are you still mulling it over?